# Consulta socket io en nodejs

Tags: nodejs, socket

Intento enviar datos desde un cliente a un endpoint en nodejs y con socket io graficar esto en tiempo real en una gráfica de `temperatura vs tiempo`.

Parte del cliente:

```
else{

  sensors=["Rimac","Cercado"];

  for (sensor in sensors){
  var date = new Date().toJSON();

  var datos={
    name:sensors[sensor],
    valor:Math.random()*20,
    fecha:date
  };

console.log(datos);
    var options = {
  uri: 'http://localhost:7777/api/sensor',
  method: 'POST',
   headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        },
  json: datos
};

  request(options);
  sleep(1000);


};
```

Los datos se envían con normalidad al endpoint señalado.

Esta es la parte del servidor donde esta el endpoint que recibe el request

```
module.exports=function(app,Sensor,io){
var express=require("express");
var router=require("express").Router(); 

  router.route("/sensor").get(function (req, res){
  Sensor.find(
    function(err, Sensor) {
      if (err)
        res.send(err)
      else{
        console.log("Exito al retornar todo");
        res.json(Sensor);

      }
      // devuelve todas las Sensors en JSON
        }
      );
}).post(function(req,res){
  console.log("BODY=");
  console.log(req.body)
    Sensor.create(
    {
    name:req.body.name,
     valor:req.body.valor,
     fecha:req.body.fecha
   } ,
      function(err) {
        if (err){
          console.log(err);
          res.send(err);
        }
        else{
          io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){

             var temp = parseFloat(req.body.valor);
        var date = new Date(req.body.fecha); 
        console.log(date);
        console.log(temp);
        //Se pasan los datos a el cliente web ahi se manejara para mostrar la grafica en tiempo real mediante higcharts
        socket.emit('post', date.getTime() - ( date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000) , temp );    
          })
       console.log("Dato creado exitosamente");
}

});

});
  return router;
}
```

Esta es la parte de la vista la que recibe los datos que vienen por post(así debería ser pero no se muestran,sino tengo que actualizar para que los cambios sean efectivos).

```
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:7777/');

    var chart;

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart', 
            defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
            events: {
                load: function() {
                    // Cada vez que reciba un valor desde el socket, lo meto en la gráfica
                    socket.on('post', function ( time, data ) {
                        console.log("LLEGO DATO O NO?");
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log("TIEMPO");
                        console.log(time);

                        var series = chart.series[0];
                        series.addPoint([time, data]);
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 100
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Datos del Sensor de temperatura'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type:'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 50,
            maxZoom: 20 * 1000
        },
        yAxis: {
            minPadding: 0.1,
            maxPadding: 0.1,
            title: {
                text: 'Valores',
                margin: 10
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Sensor Temperatura',
            data: []
        }]
    });
```

La cuestión es en la parte del endpoint que recibe los datos, estos llegan íntegros , pero cuando reviso veo que se salta el socket y me manda defrente al mensaje        console.log("Dato creado exitosamente"); , y no se muestra en tiempo real los estados en la grafica en highcharts , para que los cambios sean efectivos tengo que actualizar la ventana , y recien ahi me aparecen los datos en la consola(los que deberían aparecerme antes de enviar los datos).

### **Edito:**

Viendo los logs con morgan, cuando se envían los datos los 2 toman la misma fecha /hora ,supongo que esto es por el tema de sincronía que debo ponerle en date , y también no se muestra la petición post hecha hasta que se cierra el cliente, es como si mantuviera viva la conexión.

Comment: Deberías implementar la lógica de websockets del lado del servidor en archivos separados. De hecho, más especificamente, no deberías escuchar al evento `socket.on('connection', ...)` dentro del m anejador de rutas. Te pongo el ejemplo de mi proyecto, el cual te animo a que eches un vistazo https://github.com/joseahr/informaTorrent-Node.JS/blob/master/app/controllers/sockets.js

Comment: Jose ,tienes razón , pero como haría para escuchar el evento fuera del manejador de rutas? , pues lo que quiero es que por cada peticion post que haga el cliente se pase el dato al socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno ya lo soluciones era solo poner `io.sockets.emit` en una linea y borrar el `io.sockets.on("connection"...` pues no voy a escuchar eventos solo enviarlos.